# How to find top n% of records in a row of a dataframe using R

Tags: r, row, percentile

I am running the following loop:

```
for(i in 1:l) {
  r = volume[i,]     
  r = as.numeric(r)    
  sr = sort(r)    
  new_df = rbind(new_df, sr)
}
```

Now after sorting each row, i want to save the top 30 percent of the records in each row in a separate data frame, and bottom 30 percent of the records in a separate data frame. The number of records might differ each time the loop is run due to existence of NA values.How can i do this?

Comment: please post sample data and expected result as well

Comment: If the number of items may vary, then how do you expect `rbind` to succeed? It's designed to work with items of constant length.

Answer (score 0):

You might have something like this:

```
l=nrow(volume)
new_df=data.frame()

for(i in 1:l) { #i=1
  r = volume[i,]     
  r = as.numeric(r)    
  sr = sort(r,na.last = TRUE)    
  new_df = rbind(new_df, sr)
}

# Number rec
nr = rowSums(!is.na(new_df))
upp=data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=l,nrow=round(max(nr)*.3)))
for( i in 1:l){
  nc=round(nr[i]*.3)
  upp[1:nc,i]=t(new_df[i,1:nc])
}

low=data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol=l,nrow=round(max(nr)*.3)))
for( i in 1:l){
  nc=round(nr[i]*.3)
  low[1:nc,i]=t(sort(new_df[i,],decreasing = TRUE)[1:nc])
}
```